# centering li:before content with text

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

So I have a `<ul>` that I need to style. I'm using +'s to style it. It looks like this:

```
+ abc
+ 123
+ hello
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm not able to center the +'s with the actual `li`'s. As in, So the pluses are ever so slightly off, when I need them to vertically align with the `li` text. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here's a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2FZx6/1/) to the fiddle.

### CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-indent: -1em;
}

li:before {
    content: "+";
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: .5em;

}
```

## Edit

Okay, I didn't mean align the `#content` with the other `ul`. I meant vertically center the `+` with the `abc`.

Comment: Why is your `ul` being displayed like a table cell?

Comment: `padding-left:2.5em;`

Comment: @BoltClock I was trying different things I found. That didn't work, of course.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special to align them if you're displaying them inline, because they'll flow naturally behind the actual content. Furthermore, `display: inline` is the default for generated content anyway. Are you trying to center them in a different way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
vertical-align: text-bottom;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2FZx6/4/

You don't want to have the `+` in the middle of your `li`, but on the same height as a lower-case letter. That's why you have to use `text-bottom` instead of `middle`. If you were to use letters with descenders (such as `g` or `y`) you would notice that the actual dots also aren't in the middle of the element/text, but on `text-bottom` or `baseline`.

[(Actually, the default value `baseline` works pretty well.)](http://jsfiddle.net/2FZx6/5/)

#### Resources

- MDN: [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I wanted. You're a saint.

Comment: Wait. What about with capital letters?

Comment: @irosenb: One of your examples included the string "hello world", which contains five letters with ascenders thereby capital letters shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: Well that isn't what it actually looks like in my real HTML. In my actual thing, all the `li`s are capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

Without using a reset stylesheet such as [Eric Meyers](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) your browser automatically adds default styles. In my case, chrome added 40px to your ULs.

I explicitly set the padding to 20px and it looks good, but I'd implement a reset stylesheet if you can to save headaches down the road.

<kbd>[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2FZx6/3/)</kbd>

```
ul {
    padding-left:20px;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have better luck just using a background image on your li instead of using the "+" - This way you can position the "+" (as a background image) however you'd like.

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/master.htm

Answer (score 1):

This method gives you a bit more fine tuning.

http://jsfiddle.net/2FZx6/9/

```
li:before { // add these bits
    position: relative;
    top: -.2em ; // fine tune this however you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not work for everyone but for my situation I adjust accordingly by adding lineheight to the `li` (text) and the `li:before` (font awesome icon):

```
li {
  /* li css */
  line-height: 16px;

li:before {
  /* li before css */
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

Hope that helps someone else too!